# Django permissions not being assigned to all users in a group

Tags: django

I'm having trouble understanding how to set permissions in Django. I want to have certain users who have the ability to view and modify a certain model that ordinary users cannot.

But after I assign permissions to a group, I cannot see the permissions assinged to the individual users in that group.

For example, in the shell:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User, Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
somemodel_ct = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='myappname', model='moderation')
can_view = Permission(name='Can View', codename='can_view_something',
                   content_type=somemodel_ct)
can_view.save()
can_modify = Permission(name='Can Modify', codename='can_modify_something',
                   content_type=somemodel_ct)
can_modify.save()
g = Group.objects.get(pk=1) # the group of moderators
g.permissions = [can_view, can_modify] 
g.user_set.all() # can see alice and bob, alice is the superuser created after syncdb
alice.has_perm('can_view_something') # returns True
bob.has_perm('can_view_something') # returns False
```

Why aren't the permissions getting assigned to bob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm), permission should be in the format of `<app label>.<permission codename>`.

> Returns True if the user has the specified permission, where **perm is
>   in the format "< app label>.< permission codename>"**. (see documentation
>   on permissions). If the user is inactive, this method will always
>   return False.

Replace the following lines:

```
alice.has_perm('can_view_something')
bob.has_perm('can_view_something')
```

with:

```
alice.has_perm('myappname.can_view_something')
bob.has_perm('myappname.can_view_something')
```

And make sure that `bob` is an active user.

### Why `alive.has_perm(...)` returned True

Django does not check permissions for active superuser. `has_perm` always return `True` for active superusers.

[Relevant code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2e364a0aacb49a5160896b1ca5a2619baa3f4d9b/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L336):

```
def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    ...
    # Active superusers have all permissions.
    if self.is_active and self.is_superuser:
        return True
```

Comment: This solves it I think. I'll read through the doc again and run some tests before marking it if you don't mind.

Comment: How can we make a non-super user view ?

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris, Please post a separated question with more context.